# How many chapters does ''Yona of the Dawn" volume 15 have, and what are they?

Tags: yona-of-the-dawn

I recently read chapter 168 of *Yona of the Dawn* online, which was the latest one at that time.

Since volume 16 of *Yona of the Dawn* is going to be released January 5th, 2019, I was thinking of buying volume 15 for a Christmas present for myself. I was wondering if volume 15 stops at that chapter or continues. If it continues, then I plan to buy it. If not, then I'll probably wait for volume 16.

How many chapters does volume 15 have and what are their numbers?

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://akatsukinoyona.wikia.com/wiki/Manga), **Volume 15** only has **6 chapters**. (The page also lists chapters for other volumes)

- 83. The Sound of Invisible Tears
- 84. We Part Here
- 85. To Sensui
- 86. Meetings Which Create People
- 87. Pursuit
- 88. Those Eyes are the Same Color as the Sea

I'm not sure if the latest is **Chapter 168**, but if you say that you've already read it, then *it is still not yet released in Japan as a volume* because the latest released in Japan is **Volume 28**, which is only until **Chapter 162**. As far as I know, *English volume releases always follow the Japanese volume releases*, so you would have to wait longer. Since it looks like they release 3-4 volumes each year, that is quite a long wait (maybe 3-4 years) before they release the volume containing **Chapter 168**.